# Honda CB125F GLR 2015 stuck seat

Tags: honda, motorcycle, seat

My brother's [Honda CB125F](http://www.honda.co.uk/motorcycles/range/125cc/cb125f-2015/overview.html) has its seat locked in and turning the key has no effect so it is stuck.

What is the best way to go about opening it up so we can fix the mechanism?

Comment: Did you try pushing down on the seat while turning the key?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I don't think we tried that, will do soon, but I believe it wouldn't have affect. Will report soon.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That didn't work unfortunately

Comment: It was worth a try :o)

Comment: Does the key fully turn?

Comment: Also, which lock are you putting the key in? Is it actually one of the ones you linked? 2015-16?

Comment: Were you able to give a solution to this issue using the lubricant?

Answer (score 1):

Try spraying lubricant into the lock and around it. Then press hard on the lock while turning the key.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my ZX7R.
You should find a way to get to the mechanism from somewhere else. Maybe removing the side covers and then unlocking it by hand. Thats the way I do it.

Comment: I thought about doing it that way, but the panels/fairings have bolts that are under the seat and can't access them :/

Comment: You could always try removing what bolts and screws you *can* reach, then gently prying the fairing away and reaching in to get at the cable that goes to the seat latch.